# Tabs icon shrinks on resuming activity

Tags: android, android-tablayout

How to maintain tab icons in normal stage on resuming back from another activity?

[image]

This is the code using for tab layout:

```
public void initViews(View v) {
    //Adding toolbar to the activity
    //Initializing the tablayout
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
    userid = Util.getUserObject(getActivity(), Constants.KEY_ID);

    //Adding the tabs using addTab() method
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(prepareTabItem(0, R.drawable.home_selector));
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(prepareTabItem(1, R.drawable.message_selector));
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(prepareTabItem(2, R.drawable.cmnt_selector));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    menu = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.menu);
    search = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.search);
    searchIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.search_icon);
    searchIcon.setTag("0");
    mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
}
```

Comment: you should add some code and your requirement is not clearly mentioned.

Comment: I think you are not creating your layout design properly.

Comment: but first time its runing properly, if layout error then it would not worked for first time @Rims

Comment: post your code.

Comment: A dirty fix would be `tabLayout.requestLayout()` in `onResume()`.

Comment: doesnt work... @azizbekian